# Saving keyboard input as variable

Tags: java, input, keyboard

I want to know how I could take keyboard input and save it as a variable so I can use it with the code below.

Code:

```
public void readMaze(){
    Scanner reader = null;
    try {           
        reader = new Scanner(new FileReader("Maze.txt"));
        colSize = reader.nextInt();
        rowSize = reader.nextInt();
        finishRow = reader.nextInt();
        finishCol = reader.nextInt();
        startRow = reader.nextInt();
        startCol = reader.nextInt();
```

Instead of having "Maze.txt" I want to have a variable there that can change every time I run the program so I won't have to keep editing the program when I want to use a different file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the file name using your Scanner itself:

```
System.out.println("Please input the file name to use: ");
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String fileName = reader.next();
```

Then proceed with your method as usual, reusing the same Scanner variable for a new Scanner object, this time passing filename you captured earlier:

```
try {           
    reader = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
    ...
}
```

With this, you'll be able to dynamically change the filename while your program is running.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use command line arguments:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final String mazeFilename = args[0]; // perhaps check if args.length > 0
    ...
}
```

then

```
java YourPrgm Maze.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try scanning them in through the console and changing them from Strings to ints.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int colSize, rowSize, finishRow, finishCol, startRow, startCol = 0;

    // note, through console

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter colSize:");
    colSize = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Enter rowSize:");
    rowSize = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Enter finishRow:");
    finishRow = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Enter finishCol:");
    finishCol = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Enter startRow:");
    startRow = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Enter startCol:");
    startCol = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    }
}
```